# Information about current date as Label

Tags: ios, swift, label, nsdate

I've problems with NSDate. It's simple to write the current date in "println". How I could put my current date as a Label? This is my code:

```
    var timer = NSTimer()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,target:self, selector: Selector("update"),userInfo: nil, repeats :true)

       let date = NSDate()
        println(NSDate)

}
```

Comment: Apple has a [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html) and stack overflow has > 4000 hits for "NSDate to string". What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to connect current time and Label. I know that, i have to change NSDate to string, i saw testing code, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Actually i solved my problem :) i used something like this label1.text = toPass2 and
toPass2 = "\(NSDate())"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // Set the way the date should be displayed
someLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(someDate)
```

See [Date Formatting Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)
for more info on "yyyy-MM-dd" possibilities